# Altering a remove method to take an element from an array and moving the last value in its place

Tags: c#, arrays

As the title suggest, in C# I'm trying to alter this remove method to take the last item in an array and move it in place of the value that was removed.  This way when you remove an element, it doesn't have to take each and every individual number and move it up a space.

Here's my current code:

```
        public override void remove(ref T item)
    {
        if (next == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < next; j++) list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    next--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Here's my code for inserting the values into the array.

```
{
        UnorderedArrayList<int> u = new UnorderedArrayList<int>();
        u.print();
        int var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 12;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 2;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 29;
        u.insert(ref var);
        u.print();
        var = 5;
        u.remove(ref var);
        u.print();
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: do you inherit from `List`? `IList`? What is `next`?

Comment: @runtheplacered The over-use of `ref` probably isn't required. I think you might be misunderstanding what it does. Also, wouldn't a doubly-linked list structure be better for this sort of thing?

Comment: why don't instead of removing that item replace the value from the last item and then remove the last item?

Comment: So just replace that inner loop with `list[i] = list[next-1];`

Comment: Come to think of it, you'll also want to write `list[next-1] = default(T);` Otherwise you can end up with dangling object references.

Comment: @runtheplacered Did any of the answers help you? If so, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace your inner loop with code that moves the last item, and then clears the last item:

```
public override void remove(ref T item)
{
    // find value, if it exists
    for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
    {
        if (item.Equals(list[i]))
        {
            list[i] = list[next-1];
            list[next-1] = default(T);
            next--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

There's no need to check for `next == 0` at the beginning because the `for` condition will check it. If `next == 0`, then the loop won't make any iterations.

When the item is found, the code just moves the last item to replace the item at the found index. It then sets the last item to `default(T)` (which will be `null` for reference types). If you don't do that you end up with a memory leak: storing references to things that you thought you removed. It won't affect operation of the list, but it could cause you to use more memory than you intended.

Answer (score 0):

For some LINQy goodness:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleRemove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T item)
{
    var count = enumerable.Count();

    var last = enumerable.ElementAt(count - 1);

    var found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
        var current = enumerable.ElementAt(i);

        if (!found && item.Equals(current))
        {
            yield return last;
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return current;
        }
    }

    yield break;
}
```

Usage:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

array.ShuffleRemove(2); // returns: 1, 5, 2, 3, 4
```

If you need it to replace all of the twos with 5, remove all the `found` terms.